# Apollo Client reactive variable state is not kept in cache after refreshing the page

Tags: apollo-client, reactive-variable

I have Apollo Client running on my React app, and trying to keep authentication info in a [Reactive Variable](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/managing-state-with-field-policies/#storing-local-state-in-reactive-variables) using `useReactiveVar`. Everything works in the dummy function when I first set the variable, however it resets the state after refreshing the app.

Here's my `cache.js`:

```
import { InMemoryCache, makeVar } from "@apollo/client";

export const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        isLoggedIn: {
          read() {
            return isLoggedInVar();
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

export const isLoggedInVar = makeVar();

export default cache;
```

Here's the component that reads the variable and renders different elements based on its state:

```
import React from "react";
import { useReactiveVar, useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import MainButton from "../common/MainButton";
import { isLoggedInVar, userAddressVar } from "../../cache";
import { CREATE_OR_GET_USER } from "../../mutations/User";

const Profile = () => {
  const isLoggedIn = useReactiveVar(isLoggedInVar);

  const [createOrGetUser] = useMutation(CREATE_OR_GET_USER);

  const handleCreateOrGetUser = () => {
    const loginInput = {
      address: 'text',
    };
    createOrGetUser({
      variables: {
        loginInput: loginInput,
      },
    }).then((res) => {
      isLoggedInVar(true);
    });
  };

  const profileComponent = isLoggedIn ? (
    <div>Logged In</div>
  ) : (
    <div onClick={handleCreateOrGetUser} className="profile-image"></div>
  );

  return (
    <div className="profile-container">
      {profileComponent}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

This component gets re-rendered properly when I invoke `handleCreateOrGetUser`, however, when I refresh the page, it resets the `isLoggedInVar` variable.

What would be the proper way to use Reactive Variables here to persist the cache?

Comment: I am looking for the solution for the same I am not sure if userreactivevar hooks supports that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently achievable using Apollo API according to their documentation.

> There is currently no built-in API for persisting reactive variables,
> but you can write variable values to `localStorage` (or another store)
> whenever they're modified, and initialize those variables with their
> stored value (if any) on app load.

There is a PR for that. https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/pull/7148